# google map location result click issue

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am facing a problem with google map location. When we click on the result displaying under the text box the form is submit. How we can prevent the form submit when we click on google map location.

Here is my js:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
      new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8902, 151.1759),
      new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8474, 151.2631));
  map.fitBounds(defaultBounds);

  var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('target'));
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
  var markers = [];

  google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    }

    markers = [];
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
      var image = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
      });

      markers.push(marker);

      bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
    }

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    searchBox.setBounds(bounds);
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

HTML CODE :

```
<div id="panel">
    <form action="">
      <input id="target" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
      <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
      </form>
    </div>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

anyone can help regarding

Comment: not getting any answer after waiting long time

Answer (score 0):

Hitting the enter key inside the text box will cause the form to get submitted. One way of getting around this issue would be to convert the submit to button and add an id to your form.

```
<form id="form1" action="">

 <input type="button" value="submit" name="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('form1').submit();">
```

This should prevent the page from sumitting on the enter key and submit only when you click the button.

Comment: thanks! we also need without click on button like enter the location and click